# Heroku JawsDB-Maria Max_user_connection exceeding

Tags: spring-boot, heroku, connection-pooling, jawsdb-maria

I have a problem in builing my program to jar file. this is springboot-react program
i have 3 test files. one is rest test, one is db test and the last one is just simple test.
when i try to run the program by clicking [run] - [junit test] it works very well. but when i try to build this program to load it to heroku with jaws db it says user '****' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 10) but i already made my application.yml like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZfLH.png)

i already made my application connection pool limit to 9. one is for my local dbeaver connection to heroku jaws db. what is the solution?